# Why do i need to call layoutIfNeeded when using autolayout

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have custom UITableViewCell, inside the cell i have simple UIView , when i'm trying to get that View frame i got the 0 height and width.But when i call [self layoutIfNeeded] inside awakeFromNib method after it everything works fine. whats the problem ? why do i need every time call layoutIfNeeded to get correct frame size?

Comment: I'd show your code. There's probably a better way to do what you're doing if you're having this issue. Not all code goes in `awakeFromNib`. Sometimes `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad` make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are overriding `awakeFromNib` I assume you are using Interface Builder to lay out your cell. If so, the frame of the subviews are set up only after `layoutSubviews` is first called.